# Android ListView - Row totally covered by buttons, how can i recognize longclick on a row?

Tags: android, listview, button, row

I have a ListView, it's data is provided by a custom adapter.
The ListView's rows are completely covered by 3 buttons. What i want is recognizing a longclick on a row, not the buttons. Is this possible? How should i do this? I tried to find something about this, but never found anything like it.

(The longclicklistener is a placeholder for a toucheventlistener which should delete a row on a swipe)

Thank you

edit: updated for extra information

Answer (score 0):

Since the entire listview is obscured by buttons, you may want to create some kind of handle on the right or left side of each element.  Basically a way for the user to know they're interacting with the list element as a whole as opposed to one of the buttons.

Something like this...

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/images/5/5e/CutePress_-_Pages_list_view.jpg?20120325224257

Making the user have to long press on the listview element is a poor UI IMHO, unless you really beat the user over the head that that's an option to them.  Handles make it pretty obvious that there's functionality there either on tap or on swipe.

Comment: Well, my purpose is that I want to have an ontouchevent, so that i can swipe a row to delete it, though I encountered that my buttons were clicked and therefore the ontouchevent didn't fire. I found it easier to work with a longclicklistener as a placeholder for the ontouchlistener. So I actually do need it.